# CucumberJS - Tagged Hooks to only carry out certain Scenarios?

Tags: javascript, hook, protractor, hierarchy, cucumberjs

My feature file is currently written like this:

```
Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor

Scenario Outline: Check logging in page
    Given I go on "/login"
    Then the title should equal <pageTitle>
    Examples:
        |pageTitle      |
        |Case Management|

@refresh
Scenario Outline: Check logging in as any user
    Given I go on "/login"
    When I enter <username> into the username field
    And I enter <password> into the password field
    And I click sign in
    Then I should arrive on the "/landing" page
    Examples:
        |username       |password      |
        |user1          |pass          |
        |user2          |pass          |

Scenario Outline: User1 should be able to see all the Subtypes listed in this table
    Given I am on the "/landing" page
    When I open the Menu
    And I click New
    And I enter a Title
    And I choose the Type <type>
    Then I should see the Subtypes <subtype>
    Examples:
        |type           |subtype                                        |
        |Case           |blah blah File                                 |
        |Case           |blah blah File 2                               |
        |Case           |blah blah File 3                               |
        |Case           |blah blah File 4                               |

Scenario Outline: User2 should be able to see all the Subtypes listed in this table
    Given I am on the "/landing" page
    When I open the Menu
    And I click New
    And I enter a Title
    And I choose the Type <type>
    Then I should see the Subtypes <subtype>
    Examples:
        |type           |subtype                                        |
        |Case           |blah blah File                                 |
        |Case           |blah blah File 2                               |

Scenario Outline: User2 should not be able to see the Subtypes listed in this table
    Given I am on the "/landing" page
    When I open the Menu
    And I click New
    And I enter a Title
    And I choose the Type <type>
    Then I should see the Subtypes <subtype>
    Examples:
        |type           |subtype                                        |
        |Case           |blah blah File 3                               |
        |Case           |blah blah File 4                               |
```

How would I go about adding tagged hooks to be able to only execute the scenario(s) relative to the user.

I guess I would add @user1, @user2 tags to login Scenario and then @user1 tag to User1 scenarios and @user2 tag to User2 scenarios.

But what javaScript would I need to write to make the test flow as such:

- Check logging in... (user1)
- User1 should be able to...
- Check logging in... (user2)
- User2 should be able to...
- User2 should not be able to...

Maybe I'm completely wrong and need a different feature file for each user?

Any suggestions would be great.